# Can Anonymous users view dashboards reports from a BI site in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, business-intelligence

In SharePoint 2013 :

Does anonymous access support for BI sites where dashboards are deployed using Performance point services and SQL Server analysis server?

Where as in SharePoint 2010 this scenario is working

Comment: are you using the excel service in your dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance Point (PPS) became part of the Enterprise offering of SharePoint starting with Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007.  As a tool it was branded as "Bringing BI to the Masses."  In SharePoint 2010, it was possible to deploy PPS dashboards to BI sites with anonymous access.  SharePoint 15 (2013) broke this, either on purpose or by mistake.

work around to Fix the issue.

1. Create an ASPX page which duplicates the operations of
   Microsoft.PerformancePoint.ScoreCard.OlapViewCache.
2. Copy the ASPX page from (1) to:

   15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\PPSWebParts

   14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\PPSWebParts

Note: an IISRESET may be required after placing the files in the 14 & 15 hives.

[Anonymous Performance Point Dashboards (SP2013)](http://battey-muse.blogspot.com/2014/08/anonymous-performance-point-dashboards.html)

Comment: Hi you have any documentation from Microsoft that PPS dashboards not support in share point 2013 for anonymous users.

Comment: I could not find this on technet, but your best bet is open the support ticket with MSFT to get the official statement.

Comment: Hi i tried this scenario and it works for me, this workaround is supported in production farms?

Comment: Hi this scenario suitable to apply in production servers

Comment: I am not sure about Production, You can perform the testing in dev and i would also ask MSFT about it, while opening a service ticket.

Comment: hi this workaround works very well  for view dashboards by annonymous user in sharepoint 2013 but after when i try to export dashboard report to  excel it asking authentication , http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164782/how-to-export-bi-report-to-excel