# how to export BI report to excel

Tags: 2013, excel, performancepoint, bi

We deployed bi dashboards in our web application using  the performance point service and it enable annonymous acess for users without login they can view.

but when they trying to export it ask authentication , why it asking authentication and how to export report to excel

when i try to export to excel below page opens and asking authentication https://xxx/xxxr/bi/kpi/_layouts/15/PPSWebParts/OfficeExportPage.aspx

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure an Anonymous user have the permission to actually read the data that generates the dashboard. Viewing the dashboard is different than accessing the raw data, and the little SharePoint devil in me tells me that this is correct. You really want users to authenticate before reading data.

That said, you could try to setup the `EffectiveUserName` property in PerformancePoint Services which override the user-supplied authorization:

> If you use a connection string to create the data connection, and the connection string contains an effective user field, the `EffectiveUserName` feature will override the user-supplied effective user value with the system-supplied value.

Prerequisites are the following:

> - The PerformancePoint Services application pool account must be an Analysis Services Administrator.
> - The `EffectiveUserName` option in must be enabled in the PerformancePoint Service Application Settings.
> - You must select the Per-user Identity option when you create the data source in PerformancePoint Dashboard Designer.

To get this to work you’ll need to do the following in the PerformancePoint Service Application:

> 1. Click PerformancePoint Service Application Settings.
> 2. Select the Use the `EffectiveUserName` connection string property instead of Windows delegation check box.
> 3. Click OK.

You probably already have set up access to Analytics Service and connected to the Analysis Services data source from Dashboard Designer.

But again, I would recommend only to allow authenticated users to read (and export) data.

Source: [Use EffectiveUserName in PerformancePoint Services (SharePoint Server 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj938167.aspx)

Comment: when i try to export to excel below page opens and asking authentication https://xxx/xxxr/bi/kpi/_layouts/15/PPSWebParts/OfficeExportPage.aspx

Comment: hi it has any work around for this issue, like i ask question in below thread , and found the workaround to view deployed  dashboards using performance point and SSAS by  anonymous user.http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135682/can-anonymous-users-view-dashboards-reports-from-a-bi-site-in-sharepoint-2013